# Problemas con recibir variable get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, filesystem

tengo este error simple, pero no logro darme que cuenta estoy haciendo mal 
Undefined index: id_actividad

```html
$id = $_GET['id_actividad'];
  

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM actividad WHERE id_actividad = '$id'";
 $resul1= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

y quiero rescatar id_actividad para aplicarlo en un modal de edición de archivos, en donde debería visualizar los archivos vínculos a esa actividad, pero como no me reconoce el id_actividad me muestra todos los archivos de la carpeta Files(donde guardo los archivos).

```html
      <div id="updateFiles" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <table align="center">
                    
                    <input type="text" id="idactividad" hidden="" name="idactividad">
                     <tr>
                        <label>Archivo</label>
                        <input type="file"  multiple="multipleu" id="archivosu" name="archivosu" class="form-control-file"><!-- Este es nuestro campo input File-->
                     </tr>
                     
                     <?php
                      
                    $path = "Files/".$id;
                    if(file_exists($path)){
                    $directorio = opendir($path); //ruta actual
                    
                            while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
                            {
                            if (!is_dir($archivo)){
                                
          echo "<div data='".$path."/".$archivo."'><a href='".$path."/".$archivo."' title='Ver Archivo Adjunto'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture'></span></a>";
          echo "$archivo <a href='#' class='delete' title='Ver Archivo Adjunto' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a></div>";
          echo "<img src='files/$id/$archivo' width='300' />";
         }
                                    else
                            {
                            echo $archivo . "<br />";
                            }
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                     
                   
                     
                  </table>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <center>
                     <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editarArchivo()">Enviar Imagenes</button></td>
                  </center>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

```js
<script>
           function editarArchivo(){

               var idactividad= document.getElementById("idactividad").value;
               var archivosu= document.getElementById("archivosu").value;

               var data = '&idactividad='+idactividad+'&archivosu='+archivosu;

               $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'php/update_file.php',
               data: data,
               beforeSend: function() {
               console.log('enviando datos a la BD...');
               },
               success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
              location.reload();
               }
               })
               return false;

         };
       
   
       
</script>
```

asi se ve 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego me aparece el modal de edición de archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes un error tipografico, en el JS esta pasando el parametro como `&idactividad` en lugar de `id_actividad`, aparte de lo indicado del POST y GET. Voto por cerrar como: _Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos._

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que esperas recibirlo por GET y lo estas mandando por POST. Ademas lo has definido como idactividad pero lo recoges como id_actividad.

Cambia esto

```
$id = $_GET['id_actividad'];
```

por esto

```
$id = $_POST['idactividad'];
```

Comment: gracias por responder, pero me sigue arrojando el mismo error  Undefined index: idactividad  aun sigo buscando el error.

Comment: Umm, eso es porque estas pasando data como un string no como un array de datos. De fotas formas tengo la impresión de que el envio del fichero te va a dar problemas al enviarlo de esa forma. Aquí puedes ver como se envian ficheros por ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

tambien podrias intentar de esta forma

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id_actividad'];
```

Con esto no podrias fallar en el envio de variable por post o get... los acepta a los 2.

Comment: Ojo con el nombre de la variable que tambien cambia.